# Is it possible to not run github action for readme updates?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following action on Github actions that automatically packs and deploy a package to nuget.org every time a PR gets merged into master.

```yaml
name: Nuget Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.101
    - name: Generate Nuget package
      run: dotnet pack
      working-directory: DateOverride
    - name: Deploy to nuget.org
      run: dotnet nuget push *.nupkg -k ${{ secrets.NUGET_DEPLOY_KEY }} -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
      working-directory: DateOverride/DateOverride/bin/Debug
```

But I would like that it was not run if my update is only a `README.md` update, is it possible to do so?

Comment: [skip ci] in your commit: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/skipping-workflow-runs

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59759921/how-to-skip-github-actions-job-on-push-event

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I'd think the [`paths-ignore`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore) setting should help:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths-ignore:
      - '**/README.md'
```

Comment: For those who wants to ignore all markdown files, you can use : `**.md`

Comment: If you want to test your `paths-ignore` in a pull request, be sure to temporarily add the yml file to ignore list too.

Comment: [skip ci] in your commit: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/skipping-workflow-runs

Answer (score 3):

You might want to combine your current GitHiub Action with another like [`MarceloPrado/has-changed-path`](https://github.com/MarceloPrado/has-changed-path)

> This action outputs whether a path or combination of paths has changed in the previous commit.
> [This] action is meant to be used inside your job steps, not at the root of your workflow file

Or (opposite filter): [`dorny/paths-filter`](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter)

> With this Github Action you can execute your workflow steps only if relevant files are modified.